# The random behaviour of ownership change after mounting in Linux

Tags: nfs, mount, chown, shared-storage

So I do know that by default when we mount; the user/group ownership is set to `uid=0=gid` when belongs to the root and I read that in the mount man page.

The weird thing is I am mounting an NFS share in `/oradata` which is a directory that I have created as follows:

```
[root@sandbox ~]# mkdir /oradata
[root@sandbox ~]# chown oradata:oinstall /oradata
```

Then am doing the NFS mount:

```
[root@sandbox ~]# mount -t nfs -o rw,hard,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,vers=3,tcp ip_address:/oracle_test  /oradata
```

Now after the mount the ownership of `/oradata` **sometimes** changes to `root:root` and sometimes it stays as `oracle:oinstall` as pre-mounting.

My question is why this behavior is random? Shouldn't it always change ownership after mounting to root?

P.S: I am also using Azure Volume Storage for NFS.

Answer (score 0):

> the user/group ownership is set to uid=0=gid when belongs to the root
> and I read that in the mount man page.

I think this is an incorrect assumption. Where did you found this information? When you mount some filesystem, original directory content & permissions becomes "invisible". Instead mounted filesystem (even for network ones) permissions takes place if target supports them (as NFS do). I.e. the permissions you see after mounting are the ones which are set on target NFS server export.